# why does my variable default to a different type also when it does this I get prototype does not match?

Tags: c99

I am trying to create a .c file that computes area for triangles circles and rectangles. every time I try to compile it, it throws errors refer to pics. [this is the first part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu7Tv.png) this is the [second part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdzhK.png) and [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPlO5.png) please help.

Comment: Please include your code and error messages as text in the question itself, not behind a link and **never** as an image.  Use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for easy-to-read formatting.

Comment: Function definitions in C should include the types of the parameters, just like the declarations.  `double calcCircleArea(double radius) { ... }`

Comment: Ok I apologize about the pictures let me try that fix. Update: I really appreciate that I cant believe I overlooked that.